# Graph and tree computation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

A graph is given with set of nodes $[x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_6]$ and with set of edges:

$$\{[x_1,x_2], [x_1,x_3], [x_1,x_4], [x_1,x_5], [x_1,x_6], [x_2,x_3], [x_2,x_6], [x_3,x_4], [x_4,x_5], [x_5,x_6]\}$$

1: Compute Adjacency matrix

2: Is Graph planar?

3: Is there any Euler path or Euler circle

4: Compute minimum span trees with respect to weighting function $w$ given as:

$$w([x_1,x_2])=1, w([x_1,x_3])=2, w([x_1,x_4])=1, w([x_1,x_5])=3, w([x_1,x_6])=5$$

$$w([x_2,x_3])=2, w([x_2,x_6])=4, w([x_3,x_4])=2, w([x_4,x_5])=4, w([x_5,x_6])=5$$

I done the adjacency matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: When posting a question on this site, you should show the work that you have already done in attempting the question!

Comment: I got stuck on 2,3 and 4...

Comment: Your adjacency matrix is wrong (it is almost right though). You did not fill out the lower part of the matrix (the part below the diagonal) It should be a symmetric matrix.

Comment: Why that? Is it like if the $x_1$ is linked to $x_2$ that means 1 and opposite also? I hope you understood what I mean :)

Comment: I hope it is OK now :)

Comment: Almost there is a zero that should be a one. Last row, second to last column.

Answer (score 1):

The graph is planar:

[image]

It has no Euler cycle since $2$ is a vertex of degree $3$. It also has no euler path, since $2,3,4$ are all vertices of odd degree. A connected graph can have an eulerian cycle if and only if all of its vertices has even degree and it can have an eulerian path if and only if it has exactly $2$ or $0$ vertices of odd degree, so in this case neither exists.

For problem $4$ use Kruskal's algorithm You should obtain the following, the one in red is the minimum cost( the cost is $9$).

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped to understand the difference between eulerian cycle and path. It is planar because you can draw it without egde crossing, ok I got it. And for Kruskals I will try to find out something

Comment: no problem. There are two algorithms for the minimum cost. Kruskal's or Prim's . I like Kruskal more but you can use either. In this case there is more than one minimum cost spanning tree. As long as the cost is $9$ you can take any.